# Roles of Users in Symfony

Tags: symfony, user-roles

I have a question about user's roles in Symfony. This is because the login mechanism in Symfony spects an array of string (each string represents a role). So, in my database I need a relation one-to-many (one user has many roles). But, many users may have the same role, so, I need, at the end, a relation many-to-many (many users has a role and a role has many users).

This is not a problem, I have two entities: User and Role with a many-to-many relation.

The problem comes when I try to login, because it spects an array of strings (but I have an array of objects Role). I can extract the name of the Role object and return the array of strings with the "getRole()" method. With this solution the login mechanism works well, but when I try to represent a User entity (in a form, for example), the roles doesn't work (because "getRole()" is returning an array of strings instead of an array of Objects).

How can I solve the both problems?:

1) the login mechanism spects an array of string with the getRole() method of the User entity.

2) the representation of an User entity spects an array of objects Role with the getRole() method of the User entity.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You can always add a getRoleObjects() to your user entity.  But I suspect you are making thing more difficult than they have to be.  You only really need a true ManyToMany relation between User and Role if you plan on doing a lot of querying by role or hanging additional information off of role.  In most cases, just define and persist roles as an array.

Comment: Thank you, I end up doing that: Create a getRole() that returns the array of strings that the login mechanism uses and getRoleObjects() that is mapped with the database table.